# Cv2.CountNonZero returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCvSharp library in C# to do some OpenCV-related calculation.

Given some images, I want to stack them up similarly to [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html), then count non-zero pixels in the frames and the result image. These numbers will be used to detect overlapping, and predicate another value.

I got 3 images, frame 0, frame 1 and result:

[image]

The content of the result image is indeed frame 0 + frame 1, in this case without overlapping anything, so that the count of non-zero pixels should satisfy c_r = c_f0 + c_f1, where c_f0 = 356, c_f1 = 362. Unfortunately the computed c_r is 530. What could be the reason?

I'm using the same method to show, save, compute counts on images:

```
Cv2.CvtColor(inputImage, gray, ColorConversionCodes.RGB2GRAY);
var pixels = Cv2.CountNonZero(gray);
Console.WriteLine(pixels);
Cv2.ImWrite(fileName, gray);
Cv2.ImShow("i", gray);
Cv2.WaitKey();
```

Since `gray` is a newly created image, there can't be problem with its underlying reference (otherwise I could not see/save the real images). Why would `Cv2.CountNonZero(gray);` give me that result?

Answer (score 2):

One probable explanation of this behaviour could be: Since your images are not strict binary images(images having only 0 and 255 values), it is possible that there could be some pixel values which appear black but are not exactly zero. Let's explain this with an example. Suppose we have a 3x1 gray scale matrix with values: `[255, 1, 0]`. So visually it may appear that this has only one white pixel and all other black pixels.

Now let's take another example with two matrices: Matrix1: `[255, 1, 0]` and Matrix2: `[0, 1, 255]`, when we add both the matrices, we get: `[255, 2, 255]`. Now we calculate the zero pixels in the above matrices:

```
cv2.countNonZero(matrix_1) = 2
cv2.countNonZero(matrix_2) = 2
cv2.countNonZero(matrix_1_2) = 3
```

Now as you can see `cv2.countNonZero(matrix_1) + cv2.countNonZero(matrix_2) != cv2.countNonZero(matrix_1_2)`

Comment: This is what I would like to get later, yes. But right now contents on my images do not overlap, ie. if pixel XY is not zero on frame 0, it is zero on frame 1. This is also true for "almost black" pixels: https://i.imgur.com/UanvBOy.png

Comment: I highly doubt that. You shall manually check the pixel values, which are not zero in the resulting frame and you shall see some cases in where either `img_1` or `img_2` pixel at the same location are non-zero.

Comment: Damn, there was an one-pixel white line at the bottom of each image that I didn't notice (the images I posted are cut, the original height is 1000px). This section did overlap. c_r + width (=188) equals to c_f0 + c_f1, so everything works fine. Thanks for you help!